# Is blocking on Netty IO Threads good idea for backpressure?

Tags: java, asynchronous, netty, nio

Ok, so I get that doing any long/blocking operation from Netty IO thread is a bad idea because it will block Netty's event dispatching from happening.

However I was thinking if doing so is actually a good idea to implement a sort of backpressure mechanism.

Let me explain.

Imagine you're building a **client** application that uses Netty to connect to a lot of servers of some sort, say http servers, but it doesn't matter. You're querying a lot of servers and you process the responses and maybe even have to do some other network call to pass the result. Imagine that the speed at which you're getting data from all those http servers is much greater then the speed at which you can process them.

Now, in that scenario you could, following the recommendation of not blocking Netty's threads, factor out those time consuming operations and run them on a separate threadpool and that's great, but that threadpool will be hot as the responses are piling up from Netty's IO threads. Soon you'll see OOM if your Executor has an unbounded queue for the tasks.

So then if you actually perform all those costly operations **on** the IO threads then it could serve as a backpressure mechanism. You will only let Netty go as fast as you're processing rate is.....
[EDIT]
Alternatively, you could use a blocking queue in your ExecutorService which will have the same effect -> it will block the calling thread when the queue is full
[/EDIT]

Does it make sense to do it that way? If not, what would be the recommended way of solving the slow consumer problem in such scenario?

Comment: If the peer is sending to you faster than you can read, you should cease all interest in read operations. Not block, just don't process them. That will cause backpressure *at the peer*, which is what you want, rather than infinite memory consumption in the local application.

Comment: processing on IO threads will cause comms to pause; at some point you are running risk of server deeming the connection dead since the client has not said anything in a while, and server closing given connection.Since you are the consumer and it is pull (you request more) don't request until you can. Are the servers serving unbounded resources - i.e. streams?

Comment: Right, I understand that due to this blocking the connections can be dropped, but I can restart connections, it's better then OOM that kills the whole process. I guess I am just trying to understand how to approach those type of problems when things go async. No, the responses are not unbounded, but I am handling 100ds of connections to servers. So what you're suggesting is a sort of pull approach, when before sending a request to server I need to make sure that the 'slow' part can handle response. So I need a protocol of some sort between the two and that sounds complex.

Comment: @diginoise Java's ExecutorService doesn't seem to be particularly friendly to interrogate about how it is doing in terms of number of pending tasks. I could interrogate ThreadPoolExecutor for its queue size and then do some sort of high water mark backing off from sending more requests to the servers. Not sure if that's the best practice, but I can give it a go.

Comment: Forget Netty, this is a consumer producer problem for asynchronous calls. And I think there's 2 approaches here:
1. Blocking (for example using a blocking queue in ExecutorService for blocking the calling thread on offer() when the queue is full)
2. Backpressure protocol, when the consumer can announce it's readiness for consuming data, so kind of what Akka Streams and others do.

Blocking is way simpler to implement if only be freezing the whole event generating thread/threadpool with blocking calls. Backpressure protocol seems like an overkill for such simple scenario that I described

Comment: Well, I've just learned that http-async-client (implemented on top of Netty) is exposing a reactive stream processing (https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/blob/master/client/src/main/java/org/asynchttpclient/handler/StreamedAsyncHandler.java). Also there is the reactive stream Netty handlers implementations that can be perhaps useful as well when tryig to get backpressure via reactive streams for netty based clients (https://github.com/playframework/netty-reactive-streams)

Comment: Artur, How you implemented the solution? since i have the same problem, like while using Spring WebClient, i want to restrict call to my http server(jboss). Can you please help?

Comment: @SAtahAhmedKhan you're best bet is to post a detailed question of what you're trying to achieve. I ended up using reactive streams with Netty, which effectively translates to not reading from socket when the application is overwhelmed.